# I get "Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}Null'."

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml, visual-studio-code

I am new to XAML and Visual Studio and am working on my first project. When try to load my code into Powershell, I get the following error,

"Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot create unknown type '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation}Null'." To show the form, run the following You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. At C:\FileLocation.ps1:320 char:1

$Form1.ShowDialog() | out-null

- CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
- FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
  If I remove "xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" from my code I get the error,

"Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Cannot create unknown type 'Window'."

Below is my entire code:

```
$inputXML = @"
    <Window x:Class="JICXAML.MainWindow"  
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JICXAML"
            xmlns:fa="http://schemas.awesome.incremented/wpf/xaml/fontawesome.sharp"        
            mc:Ignorable="d" Height="740" Width="900" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
            WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
    
            <Window.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="menuButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707db2" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 5"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>            
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#6673b7"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness=" 4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
    
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#bccaf1"/>
                        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#E9A422"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                                    <GradientStop Color="#31407b" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#495385" Offset="3"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                            
                            
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness="4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="#a5a1f5">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                                   
                                    </Border>                                        
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers> 
    
                
            </Style>
    
            <Style x:Key="menuButtonIcon" TargetType="fa:IconImage">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="23"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="23"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5 0 20 0"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
            </Style>
    
            <Style x:Key="menuButtonText" TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="17"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-25 0 0 0"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Foreground,RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
            </Style>
            
            <Style x:Key="menuButtonActive" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0, 0.5" EndPoint="1,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="#31407b" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop Color="#495385" Offset="3"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707db2"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 0 0 5"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#7071f0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness=" 4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="#a5a1f5">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>           
            </Style>
    
            <Style x:Key="topMenuButton" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#707db2" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-40 10 10 -60"/>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="45"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#6673b7"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderThickness=" 4 0 0 0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
    
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Tag" Value="#E9A422"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Effect">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DropShadowEffect/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
    
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
    
    
            </Style>
        </Window.Resources>
    
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    
    
    
            <!--Left Menu-->
            <Border CornerRadius="10 0 0 10" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,10.5">
                        <GradientStop Color="#223266" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#27396b" Offset=".5"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
    
                <StackPanel>
                    <!--Logo-->
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 35 0 0">
                        <Border  Width="40" Height="40">
                            <Image Source="C:\Users\Angel\source\repos\JICXAML\jic_logo_final.png" Margin="-75,-34,-57,-141">
    
                            </Image>
                        </Border>
    
                    </StackPanel>
    
                    <Separator Height="1" Margin="10 111" Background="#46558a"/>
    
                    <!--Menu Buttons-->
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <fa:IconImage Icon="Users" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="70" Height="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Find User" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
    
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <fa:IconImage Icon="Computer" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="70" Height="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Find Computer" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
    
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <fa:IconImage Icon="Print" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="70" Height="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Find Printer" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
    
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <fa:IconImage Icon="CompactDisc" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="70" Height="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Install Apps" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
    
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource menuButton}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <fa:IconImage Icon="Columns" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="70" Height="30"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="Legacy Panels" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Button>
    
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
            <!--Main Section-->
            <Border Grid.Column="1" CornerRadius="0 10 10 0" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown">
                <Border.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                        <GradientStop Color="#223266" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#41518f" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.Background>
    
                <Grid>
    
    
    
                    <!--Top Menu-->
    
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="35" MinHeight="20" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" CornerRadius="0 0 10 0" MouseDown="Border_MouseDown">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="1,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#41518f" Offset="0"/>
                                <GradientStop Color="#2c386c" Offset="1"/>
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </Border.Background>
                    </Border>
    
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0 0,0,0" Height="60" Width="203">
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource topMenuButton}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="20,0,0,0">
                                <fa:IconImage Icon="WindowMinimize" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="20" Height="30" Margin="40,-50,0,15"/>
    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
    
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource topMenuButton}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <fa:IconImage Icon="WindowRestore" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="20" Height="30" Margin="60,-50,5,15"/>
    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
    
                        <Button Style="{StaticResource topMenuButton}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <fa:IconImage Icon="WindowClose" Style="{StaticResource menuButtonIcon}" Width="20" Height="30" Margin="60,-50,20,15"/>
    
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Button>
    
                        <Menu Margin="0,0,0,697">
                            <MenuItem Header="File">
                                <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
                            </MenuItem>
                        </Menu>
    
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
    
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </Window>
    
    "@ 
     
    $inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
    [xml]$XAML = $inputXML
    
    #Read XAML
     
    $reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
    try{$Form1=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
    catch [System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException] {
        Write-Warning "We ran into a problem with the XAML code.  Check the syntax for this control..."
        write-host $error[0].Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
        If ($error[0].Exception.Message -like "*button*") {
            write-warning "Ensure your &lt;button in the `$inputXML does NOT have a Click=ButtonClick property.  PS can't handle this`n`n`n`n"
        }
    }
    catch{# If it broke some other way <img draggable="false" role="img" class="emoji" alt="" src="https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpcom-smileys/twemoji/2/svg/1f600.svg">
        Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."
            }
     
    #===========================================================================
    #Store Form Objects In PowerShell
    #===========================================================================
     
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}
     
    Function Get-FormVariables{
    If ($global:ReadmeDisplay -ne $true){Write-host "If you need to reference this display again, run Get-FormVariables" -ForegroundColor Yellow;$global:ReadmeDisplay=$true}
    write-host "Found the following interactable elements from our form" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    get-variable WPF*
    }
    #===========================================================================
    # Shows the form
    #===========================================================================
    write-host "To show the form, run the following" -ForegroundColor Cyan
    $Form1.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to run powershell commandlets in XAML, that would be great too. Thanks for any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: Consider reducing the code in your question to a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, I'll try to reduce it tomorrow. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi everyone. I'm real sorry, but I was unable to reduce the code and get the same error. To produce the error I reported, I have to use the entire code I provided. If I reduce the code, I get a different error messages. I hope that somebody is still able to help me.

Answer (score 1):

In the line :

```
$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'
```

You have to replace

`-replace "x:N",'N'`

by

`-replace "x:Name",'Name'`

That way it will not convert the {x:Null} in your XAML.